# Can't get Oracle Connection in Glassfish

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, glassfish, glassfish-4

I am trying to get a JDBC connection happening in my Glassfish 4, but it is complaining that the URL is incorrect when I ping it.

So far I have copied my **ojdbc6.jar** and **ojdbc7.jar** files into the **Glassfish 4 > domain1 > lib** directory.

My General settings look like this :

[image: screenshot 1]

And my additional attributes look like this :

[image]

In my Oracle Devloper my settings look like this :

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Am I missing a slash or something?

Comment: ehh sorry the images are a bit hard to read. You have to right click and open image in another tab to read it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to setup the server-url in the `additional settings` of the `JDBC connection pool`. In case of Oracle datasources the database server hostname is not sufficient.

1. Remove all properties except `username` and `password`.
2. Add the property `url` to your JDBC connection pool.
3. The `url` has to be in the following format: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<sid>`

`<sid>` is the service-id/service-name

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Fixed it. This works.

I think it ignores everything except PASWORD and URL . So this setup seems to work